# Raphael JS position rectangle based on center coordinates

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is there a way to position a rectangle in `Raphael.js` based on the center coordinates (much like positioning a circle)?

Comment: I'm sure there is, What have you tried?

Comment: I think I helped with the question, accept it so it won't show unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by simply creating your own custom element, here is an example on how it can be done :

```
Raphael.fn.MyRect = function( cx, cy, width, height ) {
    var xLeftTop = cx - (width / 2);
    var yLeftTop = cy - (height / 2);
    this.rectObj = paper.rect( xLeftTop, yLeftTop, width, height );
    return this;
};

var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
paper.MyRect( 95, 35, 50, 50 ); // 95 is the center in x and 35 the center in y
```

A live example : http://jsfiddle.net/7QMbH/

This way, you can create as many rectangle you want, and it makes your code understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create your rectangle with coordinates **`x - rect_width/2`** and **`y - rect_heigth/2`**:

**Example:**

```
var rect_w = 180,
    rect_h = 80;

var paper = Raphael(10, 10, 500, 500); 
    paper.rect(100 - rect_w/2, 100 - rect_h/2, rect_w, rect_h, 5);

// The last 5 gives curved edges to you rectangle (if you need it of course).
```

Basically, instead of `100,100` for top-left, you give `10,60`. *Good Luck*